How to cache /var/lib/docker in GitHub Actions?
This is my workflow in GitHub Actions:
jobs:
  foo:
    runs-on: ubuntu-24.04
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v4
      - run: docker pull foo/foo
      - run: |
          # here I use 'docker' for building and running
          # new images, that use 'foo/foo' as their parent

I want docker pull to not go to Docker Hub on every run of the job. I tried to cache /var/lib/docker but it doesn't work because of permissions on the directory:
      - uses: actions/cache@v4
        with:
          path: /var/lib/docker
          key: ubuntu-docker
          restore-keys: ubuntu-docker

I'm aware of setup-buildx-action, but can't figure out how and why I should use it: docker works "as is", without any additional setups. All I need is to cache /var/lib/docker and restore it before future job invocations (exactly how we usually manage Maven cache in the ~/.m2/repository directory).

According to docker.com - GitHub Actions cache there are ways to use Github Actions cache to build images. I would look for the docker/build-push-action action. Its README states:

setup-buildx action will create and boot a builder using by default the docker-container driver. This is not required but recommended using it to be able to build multi-platform images, export cache, etc.

Docker works "as-is" but using the "buildx" will enable extended capabilities from BuildKit (which is now the recommended Docker backend), such as advanced caching.
The example for the build-push action shows options cache-from & cache-to to use GitHub Actions cache:
- name: Build and push
  uses: docker/build-push-action@v6
  with:
    context: .
    push: true
    tags: "<registry>/<image>:latest"
    cache-from: type=gha
    cache-to: type=gha,mode=max

But you should be aware that this is still an experimental feature:

docker.com - GitHub Actions cache: This is an experimental feature. The interface and behavior are unstable and may change in future releases.
docker.com - Cache management with GitHub Actions: This cache exporter is experimental. Please provide feedback on the BuildKit repository if you experience any issues.


I've seen these documents, but still don't get how this will help me cache local docker layers and restore them on the next job runs. I don't push anything anywhere and I don't build anything. I only pull. I simply want to place /var/lib/docker into GitHub cache.

I see, only pull and run I guess. I don't know how the "gha" experimental caching works under the hood and how would it work outside the action. Maybe you can make use of docker save + docker load (like this, or simply clone the desired image in your GH repo's registry to use in your workflow.
